# Python 3 readline() does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x

The Text File:

```
username
password
other
```

The code:

```
filepass = datafile.readline(1)
filepass.rstrip('\n')
datafile.close()
entered_password = input("Enter Password")
if entered_password == filepass:
    print ("Success")
else:
    print ("Failure")
```

Python always says "Failure" no matter what I type in. What do I need to do?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `datafile.readline(1)` doesn't read the second line, it reads *until a new line or EOF* or 1 byte, whichever comes first. Essentially, you are reading a byte.

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Comment: read two lines?

Comment: or you can change `filepass = datafile.readlines()[1]` then
`filepass = filepass.rstrip('\n')` works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your question title states `readlines()`, your question code uses `readline()`.  Two different functions
2. The `size`/`hint` parameter you have specified reads *up to* the number of bytes (not lines in either case -- bytes).

You probably meant something like this

```
entered_password = datafile.readlines()[1].strip()
```

With some obvious fault tolerance to add to your code, but not specified here.